# Forum-esque Post Count User Ranks (Without Buddypress)

Tags: plugin-recommendation

My client is looking for a ranking system similar to a forum. As your post count goes up, your "title" changes. I think Buddypress offers something along these lines but we're at the end stage and he doesn't want to take the extra time to let me convert it to a buddypress system. Are there other plugins that can do this? Or maybe someone can suggest some code to use with User Role Editor?

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you can give some concrete examples of what you want to see in the title.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Changed title.

Comment: Thanks, but I meant for you to add examples in your question about what exactly you want the titles in your client's site to look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know i have something like that and I'll post it as soon as i get home.

### Update

Bit late I know , but since i jumped a head and said i have something like that, and i just couldn't find it i wrote something from scratch.

**[Bainternet User Ranks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bainternet-user-ranks/)**

[image]

After you install and activate, configre it a bit and you can use it like this:

```
<?php $baur_plugin = new baur_Plugin();
$user_rank = $baur_plugin->ba_get_user_points($user_id,true);
echo "title: ". $user_rank['title'] . "Points: " . $user_rank['points'];?>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: ok i can't find it so I'll cook something up real quick

Comment: just for you a plugin is born :)

Comment: @בניית אתרים   OMGosh. I missed all these updates, but thank you so much for all that work!! I really appreciate it!