# WPSE Plugin Repository: The plugins that came out of WP-Answers

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, plugin-recommendation, wpse-plugin

#### Link your WPSE-Plugins

If you answered a question and made a plugin out of your code, than this is your place to share it.

**The Idea:**
An old comment from *@MikeSchinkel* during the beta phase where he wrote something like "I wonder how many plugins will come out of WA".

#### "Rules"

- Write a short - *one line* - description of what the plugin is intended to do.
- Tell how it's meant to be used: Template Tag, Shortcode, Widget, Plug & Play.
- Link to your plugins in an answer, on github/bitbucket/whatever or in the wp.org repo.
- Please *link one plugin per answer*.
- If you got some answers that would serve well as plugin, just modify your A and link it here.
- If your plugin became a commercial plugin later, it's ok to post the link here.
- If your plugin is not cc- *plus* GNU GPL 2-licensed, please mention the license.

---

*Notes:*

- I added a tag named [wpse-plugin](/questions/tagged/wpse-plugin) to this answer. Please edit the Q (where your Answer ended up as a plugin) and add the tag, or ask a moderator to do so.
- I'll upvote any Answer/Plugin added here.
- [Please also join the discussion about this on meta](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/645/wpse-plugin-repo).

---

**Important:** About License

As to a lot of discussion about copyright & open source licenses<sup>1)</sup>, i want to mention that these plugins run under the cc-license *plus* the GNU GPL 2-license, if the author didn't mention else.

<sup>1)</sup> Some related discussion examples:

- [@EAMann](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256/gpl-copyright-and-code-snippets)
- [Joost de Valk](http://yoast.com/wpmu-dev-copyright-infringement/)

Comment: Search query to find plugins by user: in this case, from [unser k](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Plugin+Name%3A%22+user%3A385+is%3Aanswer). Plugin idea: a widget to query Stack Exchange API and print a list with the results of "find plugins by user".

Answer (score 34):

### Rewrite analyzer

**Description**
Making sense of the rewrite mess. Display and play with your rewrite rules.

**Type**
Plug and play

**Screenshot**
[image: Test URLs and see matching rules with the resulting query variables]

**Download link**
[WordPress.org Plugin Directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/)

**Related Question**
[A tool to analyze rewrite rules?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/a-tool-to-analyze-rewrite-rules) and all linked to it :-)

Comment: Awesome Plugin for rewrites.  Helped me a lot to fine tune the rewrites for my plugin

Comment: By far, one of the most useful plugins I've found.

Answer (score 22):

### Simple TOC

**Description:**

This plugin makes it easy to create a wiki like TOC (table of contents) in your posts or pages using shortcode, no linking or creating anchor is needed.

**Screenshot:**

[image: simple TOC]

**Usage:**

adds a new tinymce for simple insertion, [read here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bainternet-simple-toc/faq/) for customizing and advanced features.

**Download-Link:**

[WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bainternet-simple-toc/)

**Related Question:**

[Looking for a Table of Contents (TOC) plugin for WordPress?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16046/looking-for-a-table-of-contents-toc-plugin-for-wordpress/16056#16056)

Comment: all my plugins are hosted at wordpress.org and as you know "the plugin must be GPLv2 Compatible to be hosted there."

Answer (score 21):

#### Internal Link checker

**Description:**

Adds a meta box to the post edit screen, that lists and links all posts inside your blog that link to the currently displayed post.

**Type:**

Plug & Play.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Shows the meta box on the post edit/new screen]

**Download-Link:**

The official Repo: [wp.org/extend](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/internal-link-checker/) | *Updates come from here. Only stable versions*

Development Repo: [github.com](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/Internal-Link-Check) | *Newest Features, Nightly builds*

**Related Question:**

[How do I check if I linked to a post before I delete it?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16822/how-do-i-check-if-i-linked-to-a-post-before-i-delete-it/16878#16878)

Answer (score 18):

### User Specific Content

**Description:**

This Plugin allows you to select specific users by user name, or by role name who can view a specific post content or page content.

**Screenshot:**

[image: plugin's metabox]

**Download-Link:**

[WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-specific-content/)

**Related Question:**

[How do I display a user specific content?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14445/how-do-i-display-a-user-specific-content/14455#14455)

Answer (score 15):

### WP Updates Notifier

**Description**
Sends email to notify you if there are any updates for your WordPress site. Can notify about core, plugin and theme updates.

**Type**
Plug, setup and play

**Screenshot**
[Settings for WP Updates Notifier http://s.wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-updates-notifier/screenshot-1.jpg?r=392244](http://s.wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-updates-notifier/screenshot-1.jpg?r=392244)

**Download link**
[WordPress.org Plugin Directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-updates-notifier/)

**Related Question**
[WP plugin updates](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19019/wp-plugin-updates)

Comment: I use this on most of my client sites, very handy

Answer (score 14):

#### Cron Job List

**Description:**

Lists all cron jobs in a table in your `wp_footer()`.

**Type:**

Plug & Play

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**Download-Link:**

[Github/Gist](https://gist.github.com/987128)

**Related Question:**

[How can I change the frequency of a scheduled event?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18017/how-can-i-change-the-frequency-of-a-scheduled-event/18033#18033)

Answer (score 11):

### Bainternet User Ranks

**Description:**

Create and display user rank titles based on there post count, comment count or both.
This is aimed at multi Author,User blogs which you can create rank levels in your blog based on author post count, comment count or both. Its ranking system similar to a forum.

**Screenshot:**
[image: user ranks]

**Usage:**

```
<?php $baur_plugin = new baur_Plugin();
$user_rank = $baur_plugin->ba_get_user_points($user_id,true);
echo "title: ". $user_rank['title'] . "Points: " . $user_rank['points'];?>
```

**Download-Link:**

[WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bainternet-user-ranks/)

**Related Question:**

[Forum-esque Post Count User Ranks (Without Buddypress)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9144/forum-esque-post-count-user-ranks-without-buddypress/9151#9151)

Answer (score 11):

### Really Simple Google Analytics

#### Description:

Simply adds the asynchronous Google Analytics tracking code to the footer of your website. The only option is for you to enter your Google Web Property Id and thats it. Plugin includes support for the new trackPageLoadTime Google Analytics feature

#### Screenshot

[image]

#### Download-Link

[WordPress.org Plugin Repo](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/really-simple-google-analytics/)

#### Related Question:

[Analytics plugins that allow for inclusion of _trackPageLoadTime()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16406/analytics-plugins-that-allow-for-inclusion-of-trackpageloadtime)

Answer (score 10):

### Twitter Hash Tag Shortcode

**Description:**

Displaying the most recent twitter status updates for a particular hash tag in your posts/pages using shortcode.

**Usage:**

```
[hashtag_tweets hashtag="YOUR_TAG" number="NUMBER_OF_TWEETS_TO_GET"]
```

**Download-Link:**

[WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-hash-tag-shortcode/)

Related Question:

[Importing Tweets with certain hashtags into Wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9447/importing-tweets-with-certain-hashtags-into-wordpress/9449#9449)

Answer (score 9):

### Network Terminator

**Type:**  Admin, Multisite

**Description:**  Alows to **bulk add terms across network**. You can select what sites will be affected. Works with custom taxonomies. Works from any site in the network.
*version 0.0.1 = Use with care. Any feedback is much appreciated!*

**Screenshots:**

*Before:*

[image: Network Terminator - Before]

*After:*

[image: Network Terminator - After]

**Download link:**
https://github.com/maugly/Network-Terminator

**Related Question / Inspired by:**
[Wordpress: Can I add categories/tags to all sites in my network at once?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18050/wordpress-can-i-add-categories-tags-to-all-sites-in-my-network-at-once)

Answer (score 7):

## Post Status Menu Items

### Description

This plugin is useful for people who regularly use all or most of the post statuses. Posts, Pages, and Custom Post Types are all supported by the plugin with options to toggle menu statuses on/off for each post type. The plugin adds the following post statuses to to the Dashboard's submenus: Drafts, Pending, Scheduled, Published, Private, and Trash. Each post status is followed by the number of posts in that status (e.g. "Drafts (17)"). Statuses with 0 posts are not displayed

### Type

Plug and play for Posts menu. Settings for the rest.

### Screenshot

[image: Fly out "Posts" submenu with Post Status Menu Items] [image: Expanded "Posts" submenu with Post Status Menu Items]

### Download Link

[Post Status Menu Items on WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-status-menu-items/)

### Related Question

[Adding an Arbitrary Link to the Admin Menu?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1039/adding-an-arbitrary-link-to-the-admin-menu/3831#3831)

Answer (score 6):

#### Dynamic Template serving for devices

**Description:**

Allows using different templates (and related stylesheets) for different devices (Read the comments inside the code).

*Note: Device detection not included. If you have tried it in combination with [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/), please leave a comment.*

**Type:**

Template Tag

**Download-Link:**

[Github/Gist](https://gist.github.com/886501)

**Related Question:**

[Dynamic template serving, change theme_root using add_filter from current theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12931/dynamic-template-serving-change-theme-root-using-add-filter-from-current-theme/13019#13019)

Comment: I've seen a few concepts online for device detection, whether through using the server or via the templates. Running dedicated myself, do you have a good suggestion for a device detection script?

Comment: @shawn To be honest: not really. I've looked at so many different classes and most do nearly the same. If you sort out those which are older than two or three years and compare some newer ones, it shouldn't be too hard to find what you want/need.

Comment: @ALL: Also: Try to meet @toscho in the chat and talk to him about this plugin before using it. He has more information about the pros/cons of this technique.

Answer (score 6):

## Advanced Hooks API

### Description

Experimental function for more powerful and shorthand dealing with hooks.

### Type

Provides functions to use in other code.

### Download link

[WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-hooks-api/)

### Related Question

[Implementing advanced add_* function wrappers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11231/implementing-advanced-add-function-wrappers)

Answer (score 5):

### Featured Link Image

#### Description

Add a meta box in the Links add/edit page for easy uploading/inserting images in the Image Address field.

#### Type

Plug'n'Play

#### Screenshot

[image]

#### Download-Link

[WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/featured-link-image/)

#### Related Question

[Uploading Images in the Link Manager](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/44902/12615)

Answer (score 3):

## Deprecation Checker

### Description

Extracts a list of deprecated functions from core and scans the themes/plugins directories for instances of said functions. The output includes file name and line number as well as the recommended function to use in its place. An admin can add other paths to be scanned as well as include other functions for which to search.

### Type

Plug and Play

### Download Link

[Wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/deprecation-checker/)

### Related Question

[Automating Deprecated Call Checks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43418/automating-deprecated-call-checks)

Answer (score 3):

## Default Values For Attachments

### Description

Adds a simple media options page where you can set defaults for Attachment Title, Caption and Description. Works only for images at this point, but i'm planning to extend to any attachments.

### Type

Plug and play

### Screenshot

[image]

### Download link

[Default Values For Attachments - WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/default-values-for-attachments/)

### Related Question

[Is there a way to define a default caption to all uploaded images](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/53757/7890)

Answer (score 1):

## Delay publish posts

### Description

Delays the possibility to publish a post by removing the publish meta box if the user registration date was XY days ago - you'll have to set this in the plugin code.

### Type

Drop & Go. No configuration needed aside from altering the `7`-day time span if you need another time.

### Download Link

[GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/2238167)

### Related Question

[How-to delay the capability to publish posts?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47219/how-to-delay-the-capability-to-publish-posts)

Answer (score 1):

## Pitta Migration

### Description

Migrates the database `wp_options` to match `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL`

### Type

Plug & Play, no config needed beyond setting the `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` constants

### Download Link

https://wordpress.org/plugins/pitta-migration/

### Related Question

[How to: Easily Move a WordPress Install from Development to Production?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/199283/5433)