# WP plugin updates

Tags: plugins

I wrote a plugin for WordPress which requires regular updates.

Is it possible to notify user of new version being available (some of the other plugins have some kind of this option - when new version is available user can see it in his admin panel and update - everything using some built-in WP functions...)

Answer (score 3):

There is a [library for you](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2010/09/02/automatic-updates-for-any-plugin/). :)

Answer (score 0):

I just released this plugin yesterday that does what you want: [WP Updates Notifier](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-updates-notifier/)

You can get your users to use this to be notified or take the plugin and bundle it into your plugin and modify to only notify about your plugin.