# WP plugin updates

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WP plugin updates](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19019/wp-plugin-updates)

I wrote a plugin for WordPress which requires regular updates.

Is it possible to notify user of new version being available (some of the other plugins have some kind of this option - when new version is available user can see it in his admin panel and update - everything using some built-in WP functions...)

Answer (score 0):

This is done for you automatically if you place it in the plugin repository:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/