# How does WordPress handle permalinks?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, redirect

WordPress auto corrects the permalinks(URLs) even if it is entered incorrectly. For e.g. WordPress will land you in `example.com/some-post` even if you enter `example.com/idontexist/some-post` or even `example.com/some`

It could be that, WordPress uses RegEx like or some matching algorithm that compares from right to left and if it finds a match, it will take you to the page even if there are `/.*/` left on the left. Just a guess! How does WordPress do this?

Edit: I also noticed that the .htaccess file checks for virtual file/directories using `!f` and `!d` and redirects the request to index.php on the blog folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The redirect_canonical function in /wp-includes/canonical.php is called on any given URL and will attempt to best-guess the URL the user wanted, and redirect them to there, when a URL does not exist. It has a whole huge amount of code to do this for all sorts of common errors.

Comment: Upvoted for "whole huge amount" :D.

Answer (score 3):

Use @JanFabry "Rewrite Analyzer" Plugin, over [here in the "official" WPSE Plugin repository](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18459/wpse-plugin-repository-show-the-plugins-that-came-out-of-wp-answers/18553#18553)

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple. WordPress makes use of LIKE operator in SQL query to guess the complete URL from the partial URL *when it's a 404 page*

Check this code taken from /wp-includes/canonical.php `redirect_guess_404_permalink()` function

```
$where = $wpdb->prepare( 'post_name LIKE %s', $wpdb->esc_like( get_query_var( 'name' ) ) . '%' );
```