# Post visibility on the basis of roles

Tags: posts

How to make a post visible to only:

1. The post author, irrespective of its user role.
2. All users from a specific user role.

Other then these, no one should be able to see the post.

How should I approach this.

Note that I have only three user roles in WP. Admin, and 2 other custom roles.

Answer (score 2):

Give your custom roles the capability to "read_member_posts" or whatever.  Then you could apply a filter to the_content()

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_wpse20347_filter' );

function my_wpse20347_filter( $content )
{
    global $post;
    if( author_can( $post->ID, 'edit_posts' ) || current_user_can( 'read_member_posts' ) )
    {
       return $content;
    }
    else
    {  // Everyone else sees this in place of the content.
       return '<p>Only members may view this post</p>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We already got a plugin in the [WPSE Plugin Repository](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18459/wpse-plugin-repository-the-plugins-that-came-out-of-wp-answers/18549#18549) written by BAinternet, that does exactly that.

Comment: Yeah and has been evolving much since i posted there.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I want to apply the condition globally so that I don't have to select the roles for each post. I am checking the code of the plugin to learn how to do that. But if you guys can post the snippet, it will save me some time :) Thanks for help!

Comment: And vice versa: It would save us a lot of time if you check it yourself :)