# Debugging WP routing

Tags: posts, 404-error, routing

For some posts, I see 404 page, even though posts exist, where is the place in WP where using permalink is decided what object needs to rendered?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jan Fabry wrote a [very useful plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) that I think it would be helpful for you to analyze your rewrite rules.

Comment: And it's also in the [WPSE Plugin Repository](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18459/wpse-plugin-repository-the-plugins-that-came-out-of-wp-answers/18553#18553) :)