# Importing YouTube Videos As Posts - From Playlists

Tags: youtube

I've been looking for a way to import videos from YouTube as posts in regular intervals. Preferably daily, weekly is fine too.

For the past hour I've been playing with this plug-in: 
http://www.ternstyle.us/products/plugins/wordpress/wordpress-automatic-youtube-video-posts

It offers the ability to post videos to Wordpress as posts, but only from channels, not playlists. I'd like the playlist functionality to dynamically import videos from multiple users.

Is there any way I can alter this plug-in, or create a hacked method of accomplishing this?

Comment: ah!!! the plugin's code has 0% readability.. :( It will be much faster to write the plugin from scratch instead of trying to add that functionality to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but you'll have to do a little work on your own (the Plugin is not needed).

First, load the [Zend GData Class](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html#Getting_Started).

Second, you'll have to read trough [here](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html#Playlists).

Comment: You're welcome :) - Btw: If you make progress come back and ask or tell. That's highly appreciated. Maybe we get another Plugin for our [WPSE Repository](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18459/wpse-plugin-repository-show-the-plugins-that-came-out-of-wp-answers) :)