# Tag subscription option in wordpress. How?

Tags: tags, email, notifications, subscription

I love stackexchange's tag subscription feature. Now i'm receiving email notifications only for the topics i'm interested in. I would like to have this feature in my wordpress site. Is there any good tag subscription plugin available?.

If there is no plugin available why not WA experts create one and submit it in the [WPSE Plugin Repository](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18459/wpse-plugin-repository-the-plugins-that-came-out-of-wp-answers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to use an outside provider, you can add the [tag feed](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds#Categories_and_Tags) to Feedburner.

First get the tag feed:

```
http://www.example.com/?tag=tagname&amp;feed=rss2
```

Then to to [feedburner.com](http://feedburner.com) and create a feed, then enable "Email Subscriptions" (under the "Publicize" tab).

I've done this, and it works well.

Comment: Your idea is great. But i think its better we don't depend on other services like feedburner. Because it needs only little effort to setup this feature. I'm exploring codes of other email newsletter plugin. If you can help, just give me some tips. Basically this is what i need. A tag subscription button on every tag page. When the user click subscribe link we should insert his/her user id and tag id/name in the DB. Everytime we publish new post, we querying DB and listing users who subscribed to those tags using array merge function. This is what i found so far. Give me some tips if u can

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Subscribe2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe2/) Plugin. From the screenshots, it looks like it has per category functionality.

Comment: It is a nice plugin. But it doesn't have that feature :(