# Uploading Images in the Link Manager

Tags: wp-admin, images, links

In `/wordpress/wp-admin/link-add.php` there is the possibility to add an image to a link, but it belongs to the category "**Advanced**" and is really a little too advanced for an average user, which needs first to upload an image somehow and only then to add the URL of the image to a link.

Maybe there exists a plugin which simplifies adding an image to a link?

Comment: I realize this is kinda an old question, but did you find a solution?  [I answered something along these lines](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50306/what-is-the-simplest-ajax-upload-plugin-or-script-to-be-used-with-wordpress/50308#50308) Let me know if that is in the vein of what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi, @porton, no feedback about this Q&A?

Answer (score 5):

Well, started as a curiosity, ended up doing a plugin...

:

After finishing, I went to look in WordPress repository and...yes, there's already one that does it:

[Easy Blogroll Image](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/blogroll-media-library-image/)

:

At least, I took a different approach and did something different.

[Featured Link Image](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/featured-link-image/) - [edit: released in the WordPress repository, link updated]

[image]