# Filters 'request' and 'parse_query' not firing in sites.php nor link-manager.php

Tags: plugin-development, multisite, wp-admin, bookmark

I'm trying to make [sortable columns](http://scribu.net/wordpress/custom-sortable-columns.html) in Sites and Links listings admin pages.

`/wp-admin/network/sites.php` and `/wp-admin/link-manager.php`

The problem is the following filters are not firing up in these screens, preventing the query modification. Is there other method that could be used?

```
function site_category_column_orderby( $vars ) {
    //global $firephp;
    //$firephp->log($vars, 'vars');
    if ( isset( $vars['orderby'] ) && 'site_category' == $vars['orderby'] ) {
        $vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
            'meta_key' => 'site_category',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
        ) );
    }
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'site_category_column_orderby' );


function link_thumbnail_column_orderby( $vars ) {
    if ( isset( $vars['orderby'] ) && 'link_thumbnail' == $vars['orderby'] ) {
        $vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
            'meta_key' => 'link_thumbnail',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
        ) );
    }
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'link_thumbnail_column_orderby' );
```

**[UPDATE]**

I'd like to sort the a Link column for this plugin: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50389/12615

And the a Site column for this other one: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50936/12615

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to order the link-manager.php by a custom column using this:

```
/* 
 * Sort links using the custom column link_image
 */
function sort_on_field(&$objects, $on, $order = 'ASC') { 
    $comparer = ($order === 'DESC') 
        ? "return -strcmp(\$a->{$on},\$b->{$on});" 
        : "return strcmp(\$a->{$on},\$b->{$on});"; 
    usort($objects, create_function('$a,$b', $comparer)); 
}

function brsfl_link_manager_order($links) {
    global $current_screen;
    if($current_screen->id == 'link-manager' && $_GET['orderby'] == 'link_image') {
        $order = ($_GET['order'] === 'asc') ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
        sort_on_field($links, 'link_image', $order);
    } 
    return $links;
} 

if(is_admin()) add_filter('get_bookmarks','brsfl_link_manager_order');
```

For the sites.php listing, things seem more tricky... I found an [interesting code](http://pastebin.com/x5bapTue) in [this thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/multisite-wp-adminnetworksitesphp-order-by-spam), but finally made it work with:

```
public function callback_for_plugins_loaded()
{
    global $pagenow;
    if( 
        is_super_admin() 
        && 'sites.php' == $pagenow
        && isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) && 'site-category' == $_GET['orderby'] 
    ) 
        add_filter( 'query', array( $this, 'filter_site_query' ) );
}

public function filter_site_query( $query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    $search_query = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->blogs} WHERE site_id = '1'  LIMIT 0, 20";

    if( isset( $_GET['order'] ) )
        $order = ( 'asc' == $_GET['order'] ) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
    else
        $order = 'DESC';

    if( strpos( $query, $search_query ) !== FALSE )
        $query = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->blogs} WHERE site_id = '1'  ORDER BY mature $order LIMIT 0, 20";

    return $query;
}
```

I'm using the column `wp_blogs.mature` as an [index for site categories](https://github.com/brasofilo/multisite-site-category). I guess more complex queries can be done, but right now that column seems allright.