# How to structure Multisite sites into categories?

Tags: categories, custom-field, multisite

When using WordPress Multisite with many sites, it would be nice to store them into categories. Site categories that is, not post categories.

Maybe there is a way to use some kind of site meta / custom fields for sites? Is there one? How to use it?

A plugin would be nice, or an example of a start, what hooks / functions to use.

Comment: Haven't you upgraded to Multisite yet? http://mu.wordpress.org/

Comment: Yes I have. Updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to this Question, [How to add Custom Blog Options to new blog setup form?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50235/12615), I ended up doing a plugin that does exactly that: adds a blog meta field to give each site a Category.

It's a simple meta field, meaning: no category tree. I just revised the code and updated. Available in [GitHub](https://github.com/brasofilo/multisite-site-category).

Main hooks:

- [`add_signup_meta`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-signup.php#L210)
- [`signup_blogform`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-signup.php#L112)
- [`wpmu_new_blog`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/ms-functions.php#L996)

[image: multisite categories]

Comment: Would be nice to click the column header to sort sites by category, like "domain" and "last updated".

Comment: @JensTörnell, I [tried it once](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50906/12615). Checking again now: a `query` filter has to be applied to manipulate [this SQL command](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-ms-sites-list-table.php#L50), but I don't know how to do it.