# Sort by site/blog column in Multisite

Tags: multisite, sort, columns

I use WordPress Multisite and made a plugin that adds columns with some data. My code is based on this [WP Engineer article](http://wpengineer.com/2188/view-blog-id-in-wordpress-multisite/).

The key function in WordPress Multisite is `manage_sites_custom_column`. And the problem is that I want to be able to sort the column I created.

I tried the code in this [Scribu's article](http://scribu.net/wordpress/custom-sortable-columns.html) but it is based on `manage_posts_custom_column` for single sites.

Answer (score 0):

I [tried to solve](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50906/12615) this issue before. Taking a second look at it, we can alter the sites list using the `query` filter hook.

Supposing our custom sort URL is
**`http://example.com/wp-admin/network/sites.php?orderby=site_category`**

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function()
{
    global $pagenow;
    if( 
        is_super_admin() 
        && 'sites.php' == $pagenow
        && isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) 
        && 'site_category' == $_GET['orderby'] 
    ) 
        add_filter( 'query', 'b5f_filter_site_query' );
});

function b5f_filter_site_query( $query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if( FALSE !== strpos( $query, "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->blogs} WHERE site_id = '1'  LIMIT 0, 20" ) )
        $query = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->blogs} WHERE site_id = '1'  ORDER BY mature DESC LIMIT 0, 20";
    return $query;
}
```

**Yes**, I'm playing with the `mature` column. Probably, a refined SQL query could be made, but not my league... This column is a `TINYINT(2)`. WordPress recognizes `0` and `1`, leaving us with 98 options. In my case, enough to categorizing.

If `mature > 1`, the site is marked as such in `site-info.php`, but not in `sites.php`. I'm not really sure how being *mature* affects the site output.
A workaround to use the `mature` column liberally is to tell WordPress everything is ok, *don't worry*, outside the `sites.php` screen:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function()
{
    global $pagenow;
    if( 'sites.php' != $pagenow )
        add_filter( 'blog_details', 'b5f_hack_mature_queries' );

    # Hide the Mature checkbox in site-info.php
    add_action( 'admin_footer', 'b5f_print_sites_footer' );
});

function b5f_hack_mature_queries( $details )
{
    $details->mature = 0;
    return $details;
}

function b5f_print_sites_footer()
{
    if( 'site-info-network' != get_current_screen()->id )
        return;

echo <<<HTML
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
            $(".form-table").find("label:contains('Mature')").remove();
        });
    </script>
HTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer... but for others searching for how to alter the sortability of the "sites" page.

The following does not work as expected:

```
add_filter('manage_sites_sortable_columns', ...
```

Instead, try:

```
add_filter('manage_sites-network_sortable_columns', ...
```