# Assign post type to many users

Tags: custom-post-types, users

I am working on a small course engine that has a Course custom post type and a list of users. Users should apply for courses.

I was thinking about the Posts 2 Posts plugin to create the relationship, but is there any straight forward way to assign many users to a single post type (course) and see only things for that specific post type? Any premium plugin that could do that without making everything really heavy?

P.S. A user could attend several courses as well.

Comment: Assign means what exactly?

Comment: It is for a post type entry, probably that makes it ambiguous. Means just as Post 2 Posts does - add many users to a specific post type entry (Courses: English, Spanish, German..) and a user should have access only to the courses he has subscribed to (while a course could have many attendees).

Comment: In WP terms, should that user be assigned as an author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a total fluke, I saw this [WPSE answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/18549/9844) just after reading your question. It's a plugin called "User Specific Content" that seems to do exactly what you want. "Role Scoper" is a good plugin, but it's probably overkill for what you need. Best yet, the "User Specific Content" plugin was the result of a WPSE answer's code snippet!

Comment: Thanks guys, we went with a custom implementation, but this one looks pretty much appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I think a plugin like [Role Scoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/) will work for you, you can give individual users access to certain content based on their role or group.

Comment: that looks very good, but is it really for 'individual users' or for roles, as I need a granular (user-based) access and can't create a new role per user?

Comment: @MarioPeshev - you can modify both roles on a global level and individual users on a granular level.