# Is there a way to define a default caption to all uploaded images

Tags: images, captions, wpse-plugin

As the title of this answer say, I want to define a default caption to all uploaded images in my WordPress... Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: Bem-vinda ao WPSE, Miriam! - You may want to check some  notification apps (http://stackapps.com/) that will help you to follow up your Questions and Answers here. Saudações :)

Comment: @brasofilo +1 for some very welcoming portuguese on WPSE. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really no documentation for it yet, but you'll probably be able to do it hooking to the `attachment_fields_to_save` filter and inserting the default caption there.

[From the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference):

> **attachment_fields_to_save**
>   applied to fields associated with an
>   attachment prior to saving them in the database. Called in the
>   media_upload_form_handler function. Filter function arguments: an
>   array of post attributes, an array of attachment fields including the
>   changes submitted from the form

It is defined on [wp-admin/includes/media.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.3/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L861):

```
// TESTED :)
function wpse300512_image_attachment_fields_to_save($post, $attachment) {
if ( substr($post['post_mime_type'], 0, 5) == 'image' ) {
    if ( '' === trim( $post['post_title'] ) ) {
        $post['post_title'] = preg_replace('/\.\w+$/', '', basename($post['guid']));
        $post['errors']['post_title']['errors'][] = __('Empty Title filled from filename.');
    }
    // captions are saved as the post_excerpt, so we check for it before overwriting
    if ( '' === trim( $post['post_excerpt'] ) ) {
        $post['post_excerpt'] = 'default caption';
    }
}

return $post;
}

add_filter('attachment_fields_to_save', 'wpse300512_image_attachment_fields_to_save', 10, 2);
```

**UPDATE:** 
I managed to test it, and it works as is. Just drop it on your functions.php :)