# clients list using wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, functions

I am using wordpress for my new website and i have list of clients(name and their logos). I am confused how to make those editable using wordpress? Html as follows...

```
<ul>
<li><img src="1.jpg" alt="client1"/>Client1</li>
<li><img src="2.jpg" alt="client2"/>Client2</li>
</ul>
```

Should i use custom post type or something? Please suggest some similar examples or better approach to achieve this using wordpress, so clients can be added/edited/delted easily.

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to use a custom post type for this.  But don't let the terms "custom post type" scare you off.

For example, [one of my clients](http://adaptelectronics.com) needed to present a "line card" displaying their various partners.  All they wanted, originally, was the name and logo of their various partners.  After I built out the feature, they wanted to add a description for each partner.

The custom post type ended up including a Title, Editor, and Thumbnail.  The end user can create a new "partner" and enter the content in a traditional WordPress post edit screen - no need to edit code anywhere.

[image: Adapt Electronics Custom Post Type]

Their line card page is then rendered using a custom shortcode that displays all of their partners in an easy-to-read format.

[image: Adapt Electronics Line Card]

### The Code

Adding a custom post type is fairly straight forward.  Just define what you want to call it and set up your strings appropriately:

```
add_action( 'init', 'manufacturer_post_type' );
function manufacturer_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => 'Manufacturers',
        'singular_name'      => 'Manufacturer',
        'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Manufacturer',
        'edit_item'          => 'Edit Manufacturer',
        'new_item'           => 'New Manufacturer',
        'all_items'          => 'All Manufacturers',
        'view_item'          => 'View Manufacturers',
        'search_items'       => 'Search Manufacturers',
        'not_found'          => 'No manufacturers found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No manufacturers found in trash',
        'menu_name'          => 'Manufacturers'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'public'             => true,
        'menu_position'      => 20,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => false,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => false,
        'rewrite'            => false,
        'has_archive'        => false,
        'supports'           => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'thumbnail'
        ),
        'can_export'         => true,
    );

    register_post_type( 'adapt-manufacturer', $args );
}
```

Then it's a matter of describing and defining your output.  The `[linecard]` shortcode example below is what does all the work to pull this info out of the database and render it on screen:

```
add_shortcode( 'linecard', 'line_card_shortcode' );
function line_card_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $results = get_manufacturers();

    $output = '<table cellspacing="20px" width="100%"><tbody>';
    $count = 0;
    $closed = true;

    while ( $results->have_posts()) : $results->the_post();
        if ( $count == 0 ) {
            $output .= '<tr valign="top">';
            $closed = false;
        }

        $link = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'manufacturer_link', true );

        $output .= '<td width="33%">';
        $output .= '<strong><a href="' . $link . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></strong><br />';
        $output .= get_the_content();
        $output .= '</td>';

        $count++;
    if ( $count == 3 ) {
            $output .= '</tr>';
            $closed = true;
            $count = 0;
        }
    endwhile;

    if ( !$closed ) $output .= '</tr>';

    $output .= "</tbody></table>";

    return $output;
}
```

### In Addition

Once you have the content loaded into the database, you can pull it out however you want.  In addition to the line card, my client *also* has a scrolling carousel of partner logos on the front page of their site - all using the exact same data.

[image: Adapt logo carousel]

---

### Custom Meta Boxes for CPTs

I actually removed the code I use to add a "Link" field to my client's custom post type because it didn't seem important.  But adding custom meta boxes to a CPT built with `register_post_type()` is fairly easy.

Step 1: Add a metabox callback to your `$args` array:

```
$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    // ... other entries removed for brevity
    'register_meta_box_cb' => 'manufacturer_meta',
);
```

Then define the callback function:

```
function manufacturer_meta() {
    add_meta_box(
        'manufacturer_link',
        'Link to Manufacturer Site',
        'manufacturer_link_meta_box',
        'adapt-manufacturer',
        'normal',
        'high'
    );
}
```

In this specific example, I'm adding a meta box that allows the user to add a link to the external manufacturer's website.  The core functionality is in the function `manufacturer_link_meta_box()` and it follows [all of the normal rules](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) that custom meta boxes follow.

---

### Full code for meta boxes

***PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS CODE VERBATIM IN YOUR SITE!***  You will absolutely need to modify the code to fit your purposes, so don't just copy-paste this into your own system.

```
// This function generates the actual markup of the meta box
function manufacturer_link_meta_box( $post ) {
    $link = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'manufacturer_link', true );

    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'manufacturer_link_nonce' );
    echo '<label for="manufacturer_link">Site URL:</label>';
    echo '<input type="text" id="manufacturer_link" name="manufacturer_link" size="150" value="';
    echo $link;
    echo '" />';
}

// When the post is saved/updated, you need to save the content of the meta box as well
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_manufacturer_link' );
function save_manufacturer_link( $post_id ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;

    if ( ! isset( $_POST['manufacturer_link'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['manufacturer_link_nonce'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) )
        return;

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;

    $link = $_POST['manufacturer_link'];

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'manufacturer_link', $link );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed example, i can use custom_post_type, but how can i just have company name, logo url at add/edit screen, i know it can be done using custom meta boxes but i don't know how to add predefined meta boxes to register_post_type function, please help for the same.

Comment: See my edit for details re: meta boxes.

Comment: thanks for yours great help, i don't know why but after adding `'register_meta_box_cb' => 'manufacturer_meta'` it doesn't showing meta boxes at add/edit panel.

Comment: ok its showing now but its just showing 'Link to Manufacturer site' not any input box for entering text.

Comment: You need to add a bunch more code to actually create the input box, that's why I linked to the `add_meta_box()` function in the Codex. If you need help specific to handling custom meta boxes, please [ask a new question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: can you please paste yours full code for adding manufacturer_link as you have did before, that would help alot.

Comment: See my update. But please, if you have further questions, *ask a new question.* This thread is becoming ridiculously long as-is, and I won't write your entire site for you for free ...

Answer (score 5):

You could use custom post types, <s>search for `portfolio` to get a ton of examples</s>. See EAMann’s answer.

Or just use the **link manager**. For simple links with images it is good enough.

You can create a very customizable list then with [`wp_list_bookmarks()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_bookmarks).

[image]

Comment: hello, i just want to show our clientele(max 10 clients), and it would have just image, and name of client

Comment: @seoppc : yes, IMO, just the Link Manager is enough for that. And if you allow me, this plugin of mine, WPSE born, will make easier the image handling: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53797/12615

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use posts? You could create a post for each client and use the featured image (AKA Post Thumbnails) to display the logo's. You can then set the post limit to 10 per page via the WordPress admin area: `Settings/Reading...Blog pages show at most 10`