# How to set up WP Cron in this scenario

Tags: wp-cron

I wanted to use Wordpress built in WP Cron to update currency rates daily.

I use this function currently,

```
require_once(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/autocurupdate/currencyexchange_class.php');
$cx=new currencyExchange();
$cx->getData();
$currency_sql = "select last_updated from " . $wpdb->prefix."currencies where code = 'PHP'";
$currency_1 = mysql_query($currency_sql);
$currency_2 = mysql_fetch_array($currency_1);
$last_updated = mysql2date(get_option('date_format'), $currency_2['last_updated']);
$current_date = $cx->Date;
$currentdate = mysql2date(get_option('date_format'), $current_date);
if($last_updated !== $currentdate) {
update_currency();
}
```

How can I run `update_currency()` function daily using WP Cron?

Comment: Ken, any progress on that question?

Answer (score 1):

### First things first: Say hello! to `$wpdb`

The [wpdb Class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) is what you take to interact with the database on it's most basic level. Forget all those `mysql_*` functions, when it comes to WordPress. The core has a nice wrapper, that makes most things pretty safe for you (hint: SQL-injections and other bad boys). Or at least offers things, that you can use to make it safe (`like_escape()`, `$wpdb->prepare()` to mention some).

---

## The Schedule API

WordPress comes with some sort of pseudo Cron Job:

- [Schedule API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event#See_Also) It's not that well documented, but this is what comes a *real* Cron Job closest. Make sure, that you read *everything* about it and try it in a clean install.

I have written a small plugin, that will allow you inspect what you're doing. It's called [»WP Cron Jobs List«](https://gist.github.com/987128) and is hosted on GitHub/Gist or via our [**own WPSE Plugin repository**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18459/wpse-plugin-repository-the-plugins-that-came-out-of-wp-answers).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how works the cron

```
add_action('my_daily_event', 'update_currency');
add_action('wp', 'my_activation');

function my_activation() {
if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'my_daily_event' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'my_daily_event');
}
}
```

This should work. But wordpress cron works when someone visits your site and the scheduled time has been passed.