# Writing a function for WP Cron to run a SQL command daily

Tags: functions, database, mysql, wpdb, wp-cron

I usually use the events manager in **PHP MyAdmin** to set up scheduled events but since migrating to WP Engine they do not allow it and I must write a function to use **WP Cron** instead. What should this look like written as a WP function?

I have the SQL command:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = '4 hours' WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_id = 65138;
```

I need to run it be **recurring**, for example

Every *Monday* at 9am

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = '4 hours' WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_id = 65138;
```

On *Tuesday* at 9am

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = '8 hours' WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_id = 65138;
```

On *Wednesday* at 9am

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = '4 hours' WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_id = 65138;
```

On *Friday* at 9am

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = '16 hours' WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_id = 65138;
```

(I followed [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61653/how-to-set-up-wp-cron-in-this-scenario) firstly with regards to $wpdb but am not very comfortable with it to get it right and it's possibly out of date.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`wp-crontrol`](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/) plugin allows you to add new cron events as well as new cron schedules. When creating a new event you will need to supply the name of the action hook to use. I guess the easiest way would be to just setup a hook in your themes `function.php` file:

```
function update_meta_data($meta_id, $meta_value) {
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->update(
    $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta',
    array('meta_value' => $meta_value),
    array('meta_id' => $meta_id),
    array('%s'),
    array('%d')
  );
}
// Here we are setting up the action hook, notice that we also specify that the
// function takes two arguments.
add_action('cron_update_meta_data', 'update_meta_data', 10, 2);
```

Then using the `wp-crontrol` plugin you could create separate events for each of your interval:

- Hook Name - would be the name of the action hook e.g `cron_update_meta_data`.
- Arguments (optional) - would be set to `[65138, '4 hours']` for the first event.
- Next Run - would be set to Tuesday 9am for the first event.
- Recurrence - set this to run once weekly.

It is also worth noting that `wp-cron.php` only gets executed when someone visits your website, so depending on how important it is that the cron event is actually run at the specified time you could instead set up a real cron job which in turn will execute `wp-cron.php`:

```
0 09 * * TUE curl http://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: wp-crontrol saved me a lot! Thanks @Cyclonecode