# When does next Cron Job run (time from now)?

Tags: cron, wp-cron, timestamp, timezones

I would need to know how much time is left between *now* and the next time a specifc Cron Job is done.

For another answer I built a basic [cron inspector plugin which can be found here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/18464/385).

Reason I'm asking is that I'm already that wasted from working that I can't think straight at the moment. :/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For what it's worth: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar-cron/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** [`wp_next_scheduled()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_next_scheduled/) returns the timestamp of the next scheduled job of a specified wp-cron ***job-arguments pair***.

Please note that this differs slightly in functionality to the answer below, in that you have to provide the arguments passed to cron job's callback (if it has any). The original answer would provide the time of the next specified job regardless of the arguments it would run with.

---

The cron array ([`_get_cron_array()`](http://queryposts.com/function/_get_cron_array/))  returns an array of cron jobs indexed by timestamp (each timestamp will have an array of crons associated with it - i.e. those jobs which shall be triggered).

```
/**
 * Returns the time in seconds until a specified cron job is scheduled.
 *
 *@param string $cron_name The name of the cron job
 *@return int|bool The time in seconds until the cron job is scheduled. False if
 *it could not be found.
*/
function sh_get_next_cron_time( $cron_name ){

    foreach( _get_cron_array() as $timestamp => $crons ){

        if( in_array( $cron_name, array_keys( $crons ) ) ){
            return $timestamp - time();
        }

    }

    return false;
}
```