# Build a list of partners with Link, Logo and text

Tags: plugins, links

I want to build a list of partners. At the moment, I have tried with the "links" function, the problem is that I can't use html tags on the description field. Therefore I'm looking for another solution. Anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: I don't think this site does plugin recommendations anymore. I'm sure someone will correct me if I am wrong. I show a list of sponsors on my own site just in a hard-coded array then a foreach loop.  No admin UI though. Let me know if you'd like to see that.

Comment: @helgatheviking yes please, I'd like to see it. What is the problem with plugin recommendations? there are so many plugins, and it's difficult to search for the right one if you don't know what exactly is the name of the "problem".

Comment: We indeed don't do plugin recommendations, which can be read in the [faq].

Comment: You could just go the route of creating a custom post type that allow everything you're looking for. It's not terribly difficult and could be done with a little bit of coding to your functions.php. You'd then be able to style the output using page templates and CSS

Comment: I took the liberty to rewrite the question slightly, so it can stay open.

Answer (score 1):

As NW Tech commented you should use a custom post type for it. Check codex for [register_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

You could try something like this:

```
function partners_custom_init() {
  $labels = array(
    'name' => 'Partners',
    'singular_name' => 'Partner',
    'add_new' => 'Add New',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Partner',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Partner',
    'new_item' => 'New Partner',
    'all_items' => 'All Partners',
    'view_item' => 'View Partner',
    'search_items' => 'Search Partners',
    'not_found' =>  'No Partners found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Partners found in Trash', 
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => 'Partners'
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'partner' ),
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true, 
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
  ); 

  register_post_type( 'partner', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'partners_custom_init' );
```

With that piece of code in functions.php you will be able to add partners as you add posts or pages.

You dont explain where do you want to show the results. You can use [custom post type templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates) or a [custom query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) anywhere in your files to show them.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's being kind of "deprecated" in favor of Custom Post Types (<strike>I believe it won't be possible, due to backwards compatibility</strike> - [relevant core ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21307)), I like the <kbd>Links</kbd> functionality.

The following code allows HTML tags in the **`Description`** field, and also in the **`Notes`** field (as it is a big `textarea` instead of the single line `text` field for Description).

```
remove_filter( 'pre_link_description', 'wp_filter_kses' );
remove_filter( 'pre_link_notes', 'wp_filter_kses' );

add_filter( 'pre_link_description', 'wp_filter_post_kses' );
add_filter( 'pre_link_notes', 'wp_filter_post_kses' );
```

It can be pasted in the theme's `functions.php` file, but it's better placed as a standalone plugin (so, it's theme independent).
See this Q&A: [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615)

This plugin may also be of interest, I did it based on a WordPress Answers topic: [Featured Link Image](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53797/12615).

Answer (score 0):

As promised, here's the hard-coded solution I used in the past. However, as a caveat I would have to say I definitely prefer the custom post type solution.  If I get a chance, I will probably go  back and implement it myself.

```
//edit here to add/remove sponsors
// array('Sponsor Name','name of logo in images folder','url of sponsor site')
$sponsors = array(
                array('Sponsor 1','logo1.jpg','http://www.site1.com'),
                array('Sponsor 2','logo2.png','http://www.site2.com'),
                array('Sponsor 3','logo3.png','http://www.site3.com'),
                array('Sponsor 4','logo4.png','http://www.site4.com')
            );

$src = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/images/logos/';

?>
<div id='sponsors'>

    <?php $i=1;
        foreach ($sponsors as $sponsor) {
            echo '<a target="_blank" class="sponsors" href="'.$sponsor[2].'" title="'.$sponsor[0].'">
      <img class="color" src="'. esc_attr( $src .$sponsor[1] ).' alt="'.$sponsor[0]. ' Logo" class="sponsors" /></a>';

            $i++;
        } ?>

</div>
```